# When a PhD program asks for academic transcripts, are they referring to university-level transcripts only or also earlier transcripts?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, transcript-of-records

I have some questions regarding graduate admission (PHD) in us university.   The guidelines  stated  on the maximum university websites   are  that they require  academic transcripts.  My question is that, are the Bachelor of Science (BSc) and Masters of Science (MSc ) transcripts only?
or I will have to send all the academic records(verified) from the childhoods?

Comment: Probably the best course of action is to email the admissions committee well in advance of the application deadline and ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It refers only to BSc and MSc scores.

Comment: This is right, though there are some edge cases that can be confusing. Some people take classes at a college during high school, often through a continuing education or similar program. If you have transcripts from the college for those classes, some schools take them and some don't. Others take classes at a college after graduating, but not for a degree (again, usually through continuing ed programs). It's also up in the air whether schools will want these transcripts.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time—and definitely in the United States and Canada—it refers to only the transcripts from post-secondary schools. In some European countries (such as Germany), they may want to see the secondary school transcripts (or at least proof of graduation from a secondary school). However, in such cases, they will usually state so explicitly.